# "It is now safe to turn off the computer" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Previous Windows versions sometimes (when the computer had ACPI disabled) showed a black screen with "It is now safe to turn off the computer" instead of powering down.

Is there a way to enable this screen on Windows 7? As far as I know, Windows 7 won't run without ACPI enabled.

Comment: My question would be "Why?"  What's the goal of reenabling this? I ask specifically because there may be better ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: @Shinrai: This would be a short term solution for an embedded device with an non ATX compliant power supply (that we need to power other parts of the device). We'd like to inform the user when its safe to pull the plug.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

According to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-disable-acpi-in-windows-7-64-bit-version/70ea3bbd-1667-4aad-97c4-bbaa6d317371:

> You can't disable ACPI in Windows 7. It is required. There is no
>   NON-ACPI HAL.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819760). You have to set registry `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT::DontPowerOffAfterShutdown` value to `1`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 (and presumably Server 2008), enabling "Do Not Turn Off System Power after a Windows System Shutdown Has Occurred" in Group Policy does the trick after installing the hotfix:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2660114